# Как получить все значения массива в процентном соотношении?

Tags: javascript

```js
let arr = [0,100,200,50]; // исходный массив

// получить каждое значение в процетном выражении
arr = [0,50,100,25]; // %

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Можете пояснить, что Вы имеете в виду под "процентным соотношением"?

Comment: @4500zenja из исходного массива максимальное значение это 100 (100%) минимальное 0 (0%)

Comment: ну найдите максимум и минимум. это будет 100% и 0%)) потом найдите от каждого числа процент от максимума

Comment: То есть нужно вставить в финальный массив 0% от 1, 50% от 100, 100% от 200 и 25% от 50?

Comment: @Алексей пробовал находить процент по формуле `((max - min) / min) * 100` но выводит не верно, может что то не правильно считаю

Comment: ну вы в школе не проходили как процент от числа считать?)

Comment: @Алексей проходил, только не понял как все это вывести в массив

Comment: Странно, проходили... тогда что это за формула `((max - min) / min) * 100` ? Где так преподают высчитывать процент?

Comment: "только не понял как все это вывести в массив" --- так вы не поняли как процент считать или как в массив выводить? .......в массив - добавлять `.push`, по массиву пробегаться - цикл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function perc(arr) {
  const max = Math.max(...arr);
  const min = Math.min(...arr);
  return [0, ...arr.map(e => e / max * 100).slice(1)];
}

console.log(perc([0, 100, 200, 50]));
console.log(perc([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(perc([20, 60, 80, 200]));
```

Comment: это работает только если `min` - это 0.

Comment: теперь `min` не используется :)

Comment: @Grundy, ну шо ж поделать

Comment: вообще странно, нужно больше примеров. почему, например, в примере с 1,2,3,4,5 - между первым и вторым разрыв 40, а между остальными - 20. В значениях же одинаковое расстояние

Comment: @Grundy, кстати да. Сейчас подумаю. Казалось бы тривиальная задача...

Comment: Тут проблема в том, что непонятно проценты от чего должны быть